# It looks like the keyword "in" is used as a variable

Tags: elm

Pasting the following code in http://elm-lang.org/try and clicking on "Compile" :

```
import Html exposing (text)

main =
  let (x, y, _) = List.foldL (\elem (sum, diff, mult) ->
      (sum + elem, elem - diff, mult * elem)
    ) (0, 0, 0) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] in
  text ("Hello, World!" ++ toString x)
```

results in an unexpected error:

> Detected errors in 1 module.
>   -- SYNTAX PROBLEM ------------------------------------------------------------
>
> It looks like the keyword `in` is being used as a variable.
>
> 7|     ) (0, 0, 0) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] in
>                                                                              ^
>   Rename it to something else.

What is wrong here? Parentheses match.

Comment: Could you please report it to https://github.com/elm-lang/error-message-catalog to improve the error message

Comment: Thanks. Done: https://github.com/elm-lang/error-message-catalog/pull/249

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indentation is important in Elm, and you've got a closing parenthesis that is too far to the left (the second to last line). Changing it to this will be valid code (also, it's `List.foldl`, not `foldL`):

```
main =
  let (x, y, _) = List.foldl (\elem (sum, diff, mult) ->
      (sum + elem, elem - diff, mult * elem)
      ) (0, 0, 0) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] in
  text ("Hello, World!" ++ toString x)
```

It is probably more idiomatic to put the `in` statement on its own line, aligned with `let`, just for keeping things clear:

```
main =
  let (x, y, _) = List.foldl (\elem (sum, diff, mult) ->
      (sum + elem, elem - diff, mult * elem)
      ) (0, 0, 0) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  in
  text ("Hello, World!" ++ toString x)
```

You could also incorporate [`elm-format`](https://github.com/avh4/elm-format) into your editing process to automatically format your code on save.

Comment: Good. Thanks I did not know that indentation was so important inside parentheses.